# The radius of convergence of the p-adic exponential function.

Tags: p-adic-analysis, differential-equations

As every number theorist learns, the radius of convergence of $exp(x)$, defined by the usual power series in a neighborhood of zero, is
$$\rho = p^{-1/(p-1)}.$$
This is typically proven by computing the $p$-adic absolute value of $n!$.

I imagine that this might also be proven by using the fact that the differential equation $Df - f = 0$ (to which $f(x) = exp(x)$ is a solution) has an irregular singular point at $\infty$.  My intuition in the $p$-adic case, from looking at a paper of Bombieri and Dwork a long time ago, is that this irregular singular point "pushes" convergence away from infinity -- hence the relatively small radius of convergence of $exp(x)$ $p$-adically, near zero.

Is there a somewhat general statement along these lines -- that an irregular singular point of a differential equation at a point $s$ (on a smooth projective curve, let's say) will cause the (generic?) radius of convergence of a series solution to the differential equation at a point $t$ to be less than something (involving $s$, $t$, and invariants of irregular singular points, etc.)?  Something that, when you "plug in" the differential equation $Df - f = 0$, and the points $s = \infty$ and $t = 0$, will output the radius of convergence of $exp(x)$?

Comment: Marty: your radius of convergence is wrong. The series exp(x) doesn't converge at 1 but it's less than your radius. Take a reciprocal.

Comment: Whoops.  Forgot a minus sign.  It's corrected now.

Comment: @Marty: it's good that you did say "...as every number theorist *learns* ..." :)  (I am not confident about my ability to write down the formula for the radius of convergence from memory either.)  Anyway, very interesting question!

Comment: It will indeed be interesting if this approach can predict the radius of convergence; but I like to look at the exponential as a secondary thing, the inverse of the $p$-adically much more fundamental logarithm. This is defined on the whole open unit disk, with derivative a unit, so $\exp$ can be defined only on an open disk of the same size as the one in which $\log$ is one-to-one, in other words on the disk $z\colon v(z)>1/(p-1)$. No need for memory here: sketch the Newton polygon of the log and see what (nonunit) homothetic conjugation needs to be applied to make the result integral.

Comment: @Pete:  Yes, I changed it to "learns" after I realized that I had to think for a bit to recall the exponent of $p$ (and I forgot the sign on the first try).  The way I remember it is that the p-adic exponential converges on $p Z_p$ for $p \neq 2$, and $p^2 Z_p$ for $p = 2$ -- this helps me remember the fraction when I forget.

Comment: @Lubin:  I'm not personally interested in the convergence of $exp$, though I appreciate that $log$ might be more fundamental in some way, and one can derive properties of $exp$ from it.  

I'm interested in applying some result about the effect of irregular singular points on convergence to solutions of other $p$-adic differential equations (defined on various smooth curves).

Comment: @Marty: Right you are. It's considerations of exactly that sort that made me delay my comment. But the exponential has, in some sense, no properties, at least in comparison to the log, which has loads of structure (I'm thinking of how the roots are placed.) Maybe, like Abel, you'd get a handle on things by looking at the inverse of any function you got as a solution of a DE?

Comment: Have you tried writing to Kiran Kedlaya? I went to the early lectures of Kiran's course on p-adic diff eq http://www-math.mit.edu/~kedlaya/18.787/calendar.html , and gathered this is where he was heading, but I didn't stick around long enough to learn the answer.

Comment: Hi David:  I remember asking Kiran a question a few years ago about a p-adic differential equation.  He mentioned something about irregular singular points, which I didn't really understand at the time (and I think it was a quick question in a hallway).  Now I realize I still don't understand even the simple case in this question.  Maybe you're right and it's time I talk to Kiran again (unless someone answers the question here in the next 2 days).  

Comment: Newton's method λb ↦(b - f(b)/f'(b)) can lift solutions mod pⁿℤ to pⁿ⁺¹ℤ